# Pass array with a string and int to another class

Tags: java, arrays

I am new to Java and I have failed to find anything about this case.

I am basically trying to pass this array called **vakken** to a new class called **Vak**, 
Vak expects to receive a String and a int.

```
        Vak[] vakken = new Vak[1];
        vakken[0] = new Vak("Test",3);

        Vak vak = new Vak(vakken[0]);
```

Whenever I try the code above I get this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
at ectsmonitor2.Vak.<init>(Vak.java:24)
at ectsmonitor2.ECTSmonitor2.main(ECTSmonitor2.java:27)
Java Result: 1
```

Vak.class

```
public class Vak {
    public String naam;        
    public int teVerdienenEcts; 

    public Vak(String vakNaam, int vakTeVerdienenEcts){
        naam  = vakNaam;
        teVerdienenEcts = vakTeVerdienenEcts;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your **VAK** class

Comment: On a side note, public fields are usually not a good idea. See [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You haven't actually coded your constructor that takes a `Vak` yet, **you** made it throw `UnsupportedOperationException`. Put some code in the constructor e.g.

```
public Vak(Vak v) {
    this(v.naam, v.teVerdienenEcts);
}
```

Comment: To add to this answer - if OP is trying to simply retrieve the `Vak` from the array for some reason (and not create a new one) he should write `Vak vak = vakken[0];`

Answer (score 1):

This line wont work for sure

```
 Vak vak = new Vak(vakken[0]);//IDE will display error message here
```

Because you have no such constructor for this.

Create a new constructor that takes an object of its own type.

Similar to this:

```
public Vak(Vak anObject){
//do stuffs here
}
```

These type of constructors are called **copy constructors**

And generally you won't want your attributes to be **public**. Make them **private**.